# Function doesnt see parameter as a array of objects

Tags: javascript

I´m having some troubles with a array of objects parameter for a function.

REAL CODES:

```
function drawTable(x,y,numero,t,e) {

    context.fillStyle = "#ffff66";
    context.fillRect(x*146,y*146,55,55);


    var color;

    if (e[numero].tocado == "rojo") {
        color = "#cc3300"
    } else if (e[numero].tocado == "azul") {
        color = "#0099ff";
    } else {
        color = "#66ff66";
    }

    context.fillStyle = color;
    if (t==0 && x < 4) {
        context.fillRect((x*146)+55,(y*146)+9,91,39);
    }
    if (t==1){
        context.fillRect((x*146)+9,(y*146)+55,39,91);
    }

    if (x==4) {
        if (y<4) {
            if (t==1) {
                drawTable(0,y+1,numero+1,0,e);
            } else {
                drawTable(0,y,numero,1,e);
            }
        }
    } else {
        drawTable(x+1,y,numero+1,t,e);
    }
    return;     
}

socket.on("start", function (data) {
    game = data;
    drawTable(0,0,0,0,game.elements);
   //....
 }
"Data is a object:"
function Game() {
   this.turno = "";
   this.puntuacion_rojo = 0;
   this.puntuacion_azul = 0;
   this.elements = [];
}

"elements built"
 this.elements.push({
        id: 
        tipo: 
        tocado: ,
        left: 
        top: 
        width: 
        height:
        });
```

The error is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tocado' of undefined.

in the line

```
if (e[numero].tocado == "rojo") {
```

Data isn't empty, I tested it, It returns from the server correctly.

Comment: Use `var e = [{}];`. Otherwise it isn't an array (so you can't access the 0th item) and doesn't have any objects in it (so you can't set any `hello` property)

Comment: `e` is `undefined` not an array of objects (you never assigned a value to `e`). Why do *you* think JS should think it is an array of objects?

Comment: Well, auto-vivification isn't in JS feature list, but it might have been. )) What I'm really wondering about is why this approach (working with array of objects) is even needed here.

Comment: updated to show the real codes

Comment: But maybe `data.elements` doesn't exist. What does `console.log(data)` show you?

Answer (score 3):

> So, the problem is that "cosa" "thinks" e isnt a array of objects

You're mistaken. `cosa` isn't even ever called. The thread stops when an uncaught exception is thrown. Since `e` is undefined, you get an exception on this line:

```
e[0].hello = "hello!";
```

If you want to access `e[0]`, `e` should be an array:

```
var e = [];
```

and if you want to access `e[0].hello`, `e[0]` should be an object:

```
var e = [];
e[0] = {};
e[0].hello = "hello!":
```

Or all of that in one line:

```
var e = [{hello: "hello!"}];
```

Comment: or `e[0]["hello"] = "hello"`

Comment: The problem is that my var is part of the "data" var comes of the server, so I have a array of objects as a part of "data".

Comment: @user2657856: You are not even doing anything with `data` in your example code. If you simplify your code so much that it changes the problem, don't wonder that you get (maybe) unhelpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `data.elements` is an empty array, so `e[0]` returns undefined. Perhaps you meant to put that `this.elements.push(…)` line inside the Game function?

Comment: I tested declaring: var a= data.elements[0], isnt empty, it has some value, also data.elements[0].tocado is set.